# Abandon Transaction or Increase fee

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-fees

I'm using Bitcoin core v0.15.1 and I am trying to send my BTC to coinbase. I have waited over 72 hours since initiating a transaction and when I right click the "abandon transaction" and "Increase fee" options are still not available.

I selected minimum fee under custom and didn't use the recommended. I don't want to further mess things up and some of the answers on here seem kind of technical is there a way I can just right click an abandon transaction if its still unconfirmed for almost 4 days now?

I also only have a mac computer and when I try running bitcoind from the "bin" folder I can't type anything at all in the terminal the commands do any of the commands like -zapwallettxs. I also have never used the terminal before.

All I want to do is gain access to my bitcoin and cancel Transaction ID: 3f749994629bd22808733e98cde83fa9c85d7124b7e616df5c78420f9b573341

Comment: Go to [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) And search for "Abandon Transaction" , you will find the solution.